# Linear algebra and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider the matrix:

$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&4\\-1&2&1&2\\-1&1&2&3\\-1&5&6&9\end{bmatrix}$.

I need to calculate a basis of the solution space of the equation Ax = 0. I notice that $\det A=0,$ so the columns-vector are not linearly independent. On the other hand, for the submatrix $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\-1&2&1\\-1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$ we have $\det B=8.$ Also, I notice that 
$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\-1&2&1&2\\-1&1&2&3\\-1&5&6&9\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\\-5\\4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

I got confused, how can I calculate a basis?

Comment: You're basically done. Your calculation with $B$ shows that the rank of $A$ is $\geq 3$. So the dimension of the nullspace is at most one. But you found one vector $x$ satisfying $Ax=0$. This is a basis

Comment: @AdamMartens One *nonzero* vector $x$ satisfying $Ax=0$. Pedantic, but important.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\det B\neq0$ and $B$ is a $3\times3$ submatrix of $A$, $\operatorname{rank}A\geqslant3$. But you also know that $\operatorname{rank}A<4$. So, $\operatorname{rank}A=3$ and therefore, by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\ker A=1$. So,$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\-5\\4\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$is a basis of $\ker A$.